# Packet sending with scapy

Tags: python, scapy

I tried to send icmp packet with scapy without success,
to understand where and what is the problem. I wrote some code in python that sends icmp packet.
Of course the code is running successfully without any problem.
also in scapy the problem is present,
My internal ip is `10.0.0.8` in `10.0.0.0/24` network
the code with error in scapy for example is :

- `send(IP(dst="10.0.0.138")/ICMP())`
- `send(IP(dst="8.8.8.8")/ICMP())`

the error message is:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<console>", line 1, in <module>
  File "C:\Python26\lib\site-packages\scapy\sendrecv.py", line 251, in send
    __gen_send(conf.L3socket(*args, **kargs), x, inter=inter, loop=loop, count=count,verbose=verbose, realtime=realtime)
  File "C:\Python26\lib\site-packages\scapy\sendrecv.py", line 234, in __gen_send
    s.send(p)
  File "C:\Python26\lib\site-packages\scapy\arch\pcapdnet.py", line 237, in send
    ifs = dnet.eth(iff)
  File "dnet.pyx", line 112, in dnet.eth.__init__
OSError: Result too large
```

Note: when I try to run:

```
send(IP(dst="10.0.0.8")/ICMP())
```

or

```
send(IP(dst="127.0.0.1")/ICMP())
```

the packet is sent successfully!

Answer (score 1):

you must start scapy with `sudo scapy`

Comment: user2333552 add more detail about what you are trying to do (show some code)
you may have those issues because you aren't sudo (because scapy may need some special permissions to work, for example with datagrams) or this is simple your network issue and that address 10.0.0.8 is your localhost